# Use Autohotkey variable in text snippet

Tags: autohotkey

After many times of seraching i could not find an answer regarding my use case on Google or Stack Overflow.

I'm heavily using Autohotkey snippets like this for email:

```
:*:emailsignature::
(
Email signature text
)
```

But sometimes i need to temporarily add some more text inside the existing snippet.

```
:*:emailsignature::
(
Email signature text
%datewithtext%
Email signature text
)

::datewithtext::*** Date with text ***
```

So what i was wishing for is to add a variable inside the snippet as shown above. And of course I've tried the [variable syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#amp) from AHK, but got all sorts of errors.

So hopefully someone can point my in the right direction or even better show me an example code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the hotstrings example from the docs you linked to (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) . It shows how to use `SendInput` to send text. Which will allow you to create mix of variables and fixed text. If you don't know how to combine texts, you can also do several SendInput commands in the block.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, 576i. How would i incorporate that in the example given?  Unfortunately the Hotstring docs isn't helping me much...
Also please note: I would like to use the variable in more than one block without copy and pasting it into each block seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as a solution

```
:*:emailsignature:: ; hotstrings expect a literal string on one line, 
; but can be used like hotkeys as well.
FormatTime, Date
dateWithText =
( ; the continuation section below works when assigning to a variable
Email signature text
%Date%
Email signature text
)
Return

::datewithtext::
Send % dateWithText
Return
```

OR, you could get kind of fancy

```
; auto-execute section
V_EmailSignature := "myemail@yahoo.com"
V_MomEmail := "mom@yahoo.com"
V_StreetAddress := "123 Any Street`r`nAnytown, ID, 12345"
Return ; end auto-execute section

; HOTSTRINGS
:*:emailsignature::
:*:momemail::
:*:streetaddress::
FormatTime, Date
vName := regexReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "\W")
newText := V_%vName%
dateWithText := Join("`r`n", newText, Date, newText)
Return

::datewithtext::
Send % dateWithText
Return

Join(delim, Strs*) {
    newStr := ""
    for _, Str in Strs {
        newStr .= (newStr ? Delim : "") . Str
    }
    Return newStr
}
```

Does that help you?

Comment: Thanks T_Lube for your time/response but unfortunately both scripts (copy&pasted them) seem not to work for me. Maybe i need to reinstall AHK or try it on a different machine. (running AHK on a W10 machine with latest build)

Comment: @georg. Sounds like you should try both. What specifically "doesn't work" about either script?

Answer (score 0):

On top of all the other suggestions, I would suggest to prevent you having to write "emailsignature" to trigger the text expansion. Instead, I would use e.g. "es". This short string is unique enough with the \ as the closing character to never (seldom) collide. I use this trick for many long words.

Comment: Thanks for your tip Robert, i am using that same trick for years now. For my question i wanted to be as clear as possible.